# Spartacus SAP - recently viewed products

Tags: spartacus-storefront

is there straight forward way of getting **recently viewed products** in Spartacus. Is this provided out of the box in some service or this should be implemented with custom logic.
Also, in case this is not provided out of the box what would be the most appropriate way of doing this?

I can think of one approach:

-1- Implement custom component attached to part of current product template.

-2- This component/components communicate with singleton service.

-3- Each time we navigate to `product/:productCode` we push from the component to the custom service the product info and safe it in the local storage. This way we keep track of each visited product.

Also I thought about some router guard/interceptor logic which also might be used for that and safe the visits to `product/:productCode` in the local storage. But more clearance is needed.

Please, go ahead and share good and not so good practices :-)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This 'feature' is not provided out of the box. However, I believe your approach seems like a start on making it work for you.

Although, your current approach is fine, you can look at using `CurrentProductService`. This service contains the `.getProduct()` method that emits a product when you are in a product details page (PDP - product/:productCode or p/:productCode, etc), which you can use to keep track of visited products and use to save it to a storage.